# CSS: Same contact form, different appearance

Tags: css, forms

i'm working on this [website](http://aquila-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) and I've two contact forms with the same CSS but as you can see the one on the right is different than the one on the left... how can I solve it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening a `<font>` tag (*[which shouldn't be used anyway](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#font)*) right before your `<form>` on the right side (*line 83*).

Because of this, the parser thinks your `<form>` is wrapped in a `<font>` which makes it render different than the left one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should apply OOCSS (https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki). In other words you should use classes for the structure of the forms which will be common and classes for the style.